# Embed license information in a PNG file

Tags: png, licensing

Is there a way to embed [metadata](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metadata) about the license under which a [Portable Networks Graphics (PNG)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Network_Graphics) file is being distributed?

For example, [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xtjWx.png) on [this Question on this same Stack Exchange](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/73489/15743) is made available under the CC-BY-NC licence. Can that fact be carried along with the image across computer platforms?

The [Creative Commons](http://www.CreativeCommons.org/) offers the pages [Metadata](https://wiki.creativecommons.org/wiki/Metadata) and [Category:Filetype](https://wiki.creativecommons.org/wiki/Category:Filetype) which seem to be about embedding such license metadata. But those pages are not at all clear.

Comment: Some file formats allow for inserting comments and other data, other file formats do not. JPG, for instance, has provisions for all sorts of information. I'm not sure PNG does, but I wouldn't swear that it doesn't either. Embedding the information is one thing; ensuring that anyone who opens the file reads and accepts any restrictions is another thing. Nothing you can do to the file will make the metadata appear automatically.

Answer (score 2):

The PNG format (initially defined in an [RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2083), now standardised as [ISO/IEC 15948:2004](http://www.iso.org/iso/catalogue_detail.htm?csnumber=29581)) supports tEXt ancillary chunks with a pre-defined 'Copyright' key. These can be used to embed authorship information into the image. No specific 'License' key is identified (section 4.2.7.), but the standard does not prevent the use of custom chunks.